# How many signals can one neuron send and/or receive simultaneously?

Tags: brain, neurophysiology, neuroanatomy, neuron

I've been researching this question online and finding opposing answers. Some articles say that one neuron can only send one signal at a time while others says that one neuron can send more than one signal.

What is the the exact answer, if it is a known fact in biology? If both cases are there, is a typical neuron in our brain sending one signal at this time or "multitasking"? Does the answer depend on the type of neuron?

Even further, if each neuron is sending more than one signal at a time, what would that imply to our current medical detections of brain? Can different signals happening at the same time be distinguished at all with our technology of detection and brain scanning?

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided more information about what you read - where did you read it, and can you provide a short quote of what was said?

Comment: I'd also ask you to clarify what you mean by "medical detections of brain"... no clinical uses of brain activity care about single-neuron stuff.

Comment: You're asking a pretty broad question here. Basically it's asking for a mini-course on how the different types of neurons work. Please narrow it down to a specific question, and your last question as already been answered by @BryanKrause. While every neuron is important, we can only examine/detect large groups of neurons at work.

Answer (score 0):

A typical neuron receives in parallel many signals, both excitatory and inhibitory, from many different sources (usually other neurons). At any given time, if excitation exceeds a certain threshold, the neuron *fires* a single outgoing signal (the so-called **action potential**).

Thus, the simplest possible answer to the first part of your question is that neurons can only send out a single signal at a time. However,

- each action potential is distributed to many targets at once (usually other neurons)
- a single action potential is hardly meaningful as a signal; instead, the *[firing rate](https://www.pnas.org/content/94/24/12740)*, i.e. the frequency of outgoing signals, is regarded as the most fundamental (but not the only) neural code.

For example, a neuron along a sensory pathway might respond with a barrage of several hundred action potentials to the onset of an appropriate stimulus (a sound, a blinking light, a touch on the skin, etc.). In turn, these signals would be transmitted to many other neurons, and so on.

Mind you, this concise description barely scratches the surface of an immensely complex topic. As mentioned in the comments, the question as a whole is too broad and ill-defined.